# Redirect browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I've got a 'menu' within a Master page which include a number of image buttons with click events.

Within each click event, I want to redirect the user to a specific page.  However, if the user is already on the correct page, I don't want to refresh the page.

In the example below, if the user is already on browse.aspx, I don't want to refresh it, however, otherwise I want to redirect the user to browse.aspx.

Is the following code the best way to go about this?

```
protected void ibtnBrowse_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.Url.Segments[1].ToString().Equals("browse.aspx"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/browse.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should do this. When I click a button, it should do something, when it doesn't do anything, it's confusing.

So, when the user clicks on something that is supposed to take him to the page they're already on, it *should* refresh the page.

For example, Stack Exchange does this: try clicking on the question title here, or on the site name on the main page.